Statistical test on proxy variables
let's say I am interested in performing a statistical test to determine whether the mean of two distributions, a and b, differ. But I cannot sample a and b. Instead, I can sample c and d, which are proxy estimators for a and b. I know the correlation a has with c, and b has with d. Is there a way to "correct" the test between c and d for what I really want (between a and b)? If the correlation alone is not sufficient to achieve this, can we make some assumptions, or is it not possible? Anyone have any ideas on this?

Just out of curiosity, how do you know the correlations of $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ respectively? Do you have measures of $a$ and $b$? If so, why do you need the proxies?

well, I don't have correlations of (a,c) and (b,d) directly, however these correlations have been measured in a similar experiment and are thus taken as those values

In my opinion, if there is a strong correlation between a-c and b-d, it may sound possible. However, you should consider that even if there are strong correlations, the distributions of variables (assumptions of normality) between a-c and b-d may differ. In that case, the optimal test may differ, which can have a serious impact on your result. So I believe that it is not a good idea.
